# ASP.Net Ajax Post Error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, jquery

```
jQuery
 $(".lnkpro").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "uygulamalar.aspx/Getir",
                data: '{name: "1234"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (sonuc) { $(".resimler").html(sonuc.d); },
                error: function () { alert("error") }
            });
        });
```

VB.NET (WebMethod)

```
  <System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
      Public Shared Function Getir(ByVal name As Integer) As String
        Return name & " asdalo"
      End Function
```

Hata verip duruyor lütfen bir yardımcı olun arkadaşlar
where is the error???

Comment: remove single quotes from '{name: "1234"}'

Comment: SO doesn't (I'm afraid) support non-english speakers [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/217110)

Comment: @Satya I believe OP need to remove double quotes since value interpreted as string

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy , shouldn't this be {name:"1234"} instead of '{name:"1234"}'

Comment: I did but the problem was not resolved

Answer (score 0):

use from this script:

```
var data={
    name : 1234
};

$(".lnkpro").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "uygulamalar.aspx/Getir",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (sonuc) { $(".resimler").html(sonuc.d); },
                error: function () { alert("error") }
            });
        });
```